# Thread working with I2C blocked

Tags: python, i2c, pigpio

I have an python daemon running on Raspberry Pi.
The daemon reads and writes value to chip connected with I2C bus.
The chips are:

- MCP23008 (digital IO)
- MCP3428 (analog in)
- MCP4728 (analog out)

The daemon has a monitoring thread that performs read on the chips, sleeps for some time and repeats.
If any change occurs, it's notified to a remote host.

Some time ago I've encountered an issue.
Monitoring thread stopped reporting any value change.
I think that it was stuck on some I2C IO operation, since there is no other blocking operations in it.

I did some research and discovered that I2C specification does not have any timeout condition (http://www.i2c-bus.org/i2c-primer/obscure-problems/ and [SMBus specs](http://smbus.org/specs/smbus20.pdf) at page 58).
The problem happened once and on prototype board, whose wiring is surely not perfect.

In addition, two different libraries are user for I2C communication.
For MCP3428 python-smbus is used.
For MCP4728 python-pigpio is used.
This choice derives from the fact that MCP4728 need some commands that does not fit SMBUS transmission paradigm.
I don't know if there can be a conflict of any kind.

I want to protect my daemon from such issue.
So I have several questions:

- how do I recover from such a blockage?

  - do I need to close/open I2C handle?
  - or reset I2C bus?
  - or reset the whole system?
- do pigpio library has the possibility to set read/write timeouts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to find out what, if anything, is blocking.

In my experience Linux driver I2C problems usually return IO error 5.

The pigpio i2c* functions use the Linux I2C driver.

The pigpio bb_i2c* functions use bit banging and there is a 10ms timeout per bit (which I will probably make considerably larger).

Comment: joan, so you are suggesting that I should look elsewhere to find the block, since Linux I2C driver returns error in case on problems? Is there any documentation for the error management in this driver?

Comment: @DanTumaykin I don't know what might happen with the Linux driver.  I don't know if it will timeout or not.  I just mean to say you need to confirm the function which blocks, otherwise you might be solving the wrong problem.  You probably need to add diagnostic prints.